# Удалённый доступ к файловой системе Windows

Tags: c#, winforms

Пишу приложение для разбора логов с локального/удалённого сервера. Принцип работы приложения прост:

- для локальной папки: читаются файлы логов и выводятся в удобном виде в окне программы.
- для удалённой папки: загружаются все файлы из удалённой папки в локальную (кэш) и после выводятся в окне программы по аналогии с локальной папкой.

Функционал для локальной папки и для Linux серверов понятен. Для первого я использую стандартный инструмент чтения файловой системы. Последний по умолчанию поддерживает SFTP протокол который легко [реализуется](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23703040/download-files-from-sftp-with-ssh-net-library) через библиотеку SSH.NET.

**Вопрос:** как быть с удалённой Windows машиной (ОС может быть как Windows Server так и обычная начиная от Windows 7)? Есть ли уже готовые "из коробки" решения в самой Windows системе без [установки OpenSSH сервера и настройки SFTP](https://winitpro.ru/index.php/2016/03/31/sftp-ssh-ftp-na-windows-server-2012-r2/) для чтения файловой системы? Из условий по умолчанию: обязательно имеется полноценный RDP доступ к удалённой машине, т.е. хост, порт, домен, пользователь и пароль по умолчанию известны.

Comment: _Есть ли уже готовые "из коробки" решения в самой Windows_ - MS NetBios?

Comment: @aepot как этот протокол мне поможет подключиться к Windows машине расположенной например в Германии? Он вроде как предназначен только для локальных сетей.

Comment: Что мешает IPSec туннель поднять, если нужна постоянная частная сеть? Для сеансового обмена файлами достаточно SFTP, как вы уже догадались. Можно и обычный FTP сервер поднять - https://firstvds.ru/technology/nastroyka-ftp-servera-na-windows-server-2019 старо как мир

Comment: @aepot зачем всё это, если можно в таком случае воспользоваться инструкцией что я привёл в описании и использовать уже готовый модуль SFTP  в программе? Мой вопрос задавался с целью удостовериться что легче решения чем приведённый мной способа нет для Windows ОС.

Comment: Через туннель всё заработает вообще без каких-либо программ, в том числе без вашей.

Comment: @aepot что потребуется со стороны клиента и сервера для настройки туннеля и насколько рациональны трудозатраты на поднятие туннеля? Программа призвана облегчить и максимально упростить чтение логов, а не создать ещё 100500 новых проблем. На данный момент для удалённого сервера на Linux мне достаточно знать только параметры подключения по SSH и я могу с любого компьютера просмотреть логи. С вашим предложением у меня будет подобная мобильность или потребуется куча дополнительных телодвижений?

Comment: Ну если  логи читать, то самое оптимальное - HTTP сервер и простенький сайт-админка. ASP.NET Core в помощь. Откроете браузер, а там логи, что может быть мобильнее? Хоть с телефона читайте.